# Docker on Remote Host refused mount request : not exported

Tags: docker, windows-subsystem-for-linux, nfs

I have a windows host (10.10.1.28) I'm trying to connect to NFS shares (10.10.1.17) for docker volumes.

My NFS export /etc/exports

```
# This file is auto-generated by openmediavault (https://www.openmediavault.org)
# WARNING: Do not edit this file, your changes will get lost.

# /etc/exports: the access control list for filesystems which may be exported
#               to NFS clients.  See exports(5).

/export/InterfereFlatThickThose 10.10.1.0/24(fsid=c084acae-b3bc-4ce6-bb15-502ae8834d82,rw,sync,insecure,root_squash,no_subtree_check)

# NFSv4 - pseudo filesystem root
/export 10.10.1.0/24(ro,fsid=0,root_squash,no_subtree_check,hide)
```

With Export List

```
Export list for localhost:
/export                         10.10.1.0/24
/export/InterfereFlatThickThose 10.10.1.0/24
```

Connecting with Docker volume :

```
interfere:
    name: interferename
    driver: local  
    driver_opts:
        type: nfs
        o: nfsvers=4,addr=10.10.1.17
        device: ":/InterfereFlatThickThose/"
```

gives me the following lines in /var/log/syslog

```
Apr 20 17:18:56 cmf-nfs rpc.mountd[33222]: refused mount request from 10.10.1.28 for /InterfereFlatThickThose/ (/): not exported
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like for mounting something shared from OpenMediaVault and trying to access from Docker on Windows it looks like this will work.

```
interfere:
    name: interferename
    driver: local  
    driver_opts:
        type: nfs
        o: addr=10.10.1.17
        device: ":/export/InterfereFlatThickThose/"
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).